# Trying to search for an element with a title name in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error ("uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression") while trying to search for a particular title inside a select dropdown and making that currently selected value.

This is what I am trying to do.

```
var selectedAppName = 'title with space'; //generating this value run time
$("#drop").find("option[title=" + selectedAppName + "]").attr("selected", "selected");
```

and a working demo of the above issue. http://jsfiddle.net/BqHBf/26/

Is there a fix or jquery doesnt allow this expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to concatenate your `selectedAppName` variable properly using `'`:

```
$("#drop").find("option[title='" + selectedAppName + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
// ---------------------------^  here and here -------^ ------------------------
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqHBf/27/)**